# Should I use thread to improve performance in these code?

Tags: c#, multithreading

In my coding, I want to get some performance improvement, so I think thread would be a choice, but I am not confident with multithreading and data sharing issue. Could someone review these codes and give me any sugguestions, thanks!

```
 public partial class WorkflowService: IWorkflowService
 {
         public void StartProcess(WfAppRunner starter)
            {
                try
                {
                    WfRuntimeManager runtimeManager = new WfRuntimeManagerStartup();
                    runtimeManager.AppRunner = starter;
                    runtimeManager.Execute();
                }
                catch (System.Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
 }

internal abstract class WfRuntimeManager
{
        internal WfAppRunner AppRunner { get; set; }
        internal abstract void ExecuteInstance();
        internal bool Execute()
        {
            try
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(ExecuteInstance);
                thread.Start();

                return true;
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
}

internal class WfRuntimeManagerStartup : WfRuntimeManager
{
    internal override void ExecuteInstance()
    {
        ISession session = SessionFactory.CreateSession();
        try
        {
            var runner = base.AppRunner;

            //do some works with runner, and save works to database.
            SaveToDatabase(runner);

        ...

        //do some other works
        ProcessOtherWorks();

            session.Commit();
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            session.Rollback();
        }
        finally
        {
            session.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

//do some test, minic the true user case
[TestMethod]
public void RunParalleled()
{
    //StarterA:
    //{"UserID":"10","UserName":"Long","AppName":"SamplePrice","AppInstanceID":"100","ProcessGUID":"072af8c3-482a-4b1c-890b-685ce2fcc75d"}
    var starterA = new WfAppRunner();
    starterA.ProcessGUID = Guid.Parse("072af8c3-482a-4b1c-890b-685ce2fcc75d");
    starterA.UserID = 10;
    starterA.UserName = "Long";

    //SarterB:
    //{"AppName":"Offin","AppInstanceID":587,"UserID":"0021","UserName":"test2","ProcessGUID":"68696ea3-00ab-4b40-8fcf-9859dbbde378","FlowStatus":null,"Conditions":{"surplus":"aa"}}
    var starterB = new WfAppRunner();
    starterB.ProcessGUID = Guid.Parse("68696ea3-00ab-4b40-8fcf-9859dbbde378");
    starterB.UserID = 21;
    starterB.UserName = "test2";

    IWorkflowService serviceA, serviceB;
    for (var i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    {
        serviceA = new WorkflowService();
        starterA.AppName = "Price";
        starterA.AppInstanceID = i;

        serviceB = new WorkflowService();
        starterB.AppName = "Offin";
        starterB.AppInstanceID = i;

        //execute process instance
        serviceA.StartProcess(starterA);
        serviceB.StartProcess(starterB);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to speak without information about what the threads will be working on, but yes. Multithreading can be dangerous when you're manipulating data. Your major performance gains could actually be in your code itself, analyze your methods to find which ones take most time, e.g. places where iterations take place, etc. Then post the method here as a problem method.

Comment: hi, Opata, thanks your reply. Becuase the method ExecuteInstance() does much transaction and makes system slow, so I wanna to make the method run among the multi threads parallely.

Comment: @BesLey: When you provide each thread with its own state or data, multi-threading can be great to improve performance.

Comment: What do you mean by "transaction"? If your program is pummeling the hard drive, then multithreading will probably make it even slower.

Comment: hi, saravanan: will it avoid data sharing issue or not need to lock object? I would like to try to to this. thanks.

@svinja: it's really a long transaction, and will write data to database. Because there will be more concurrent users to run the program, I need to get performance improvement.